# Why is my Docker Running but Http is not being served?

Tags: python, docker

I recently installed DockerToolbox from https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox and installed. I tested it and works well according to the quick test docker run hello-world . Now learning how to use it following https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/ exactly step-by-step, first I created a Docker image:

```
docker build -t friendlyhello .
```

Then I check the built image:

```
$ docker images
```

Run the app, mapping my machine’s port 4000 to the container’s published port 80 using -p:

```
docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello
```

[image]
The problem is the app is not being served as expected when I enter the url in the browser.    http://localhost:4000
[image]

Even when I curled from shell, I don't get it:
[image]

I will appreciate any idea on how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to Docker-Machine and not your docker image. You should try to access the image at:

```
http://[ip-address-of-vm]:4000
```

The reason being is due to docker being run on the VM instead of your actual windows, hence the port mapping is done on the VM. If you would like to map access by using localhost you will have to set up a rule to port forward from guest machine to the host machine. In Oracle Virtual Box this can be easily done by going under the settings of the VM. Under the NAT adapter you will find the port forwarding button.

[image: VM Port Fowarding]

Edit:

I forgot to mention this but 0.0.0.0 will never be reachable through a web browser or curl command, as this just means it is listening on all network interfaces.

Comment: Thank you @William Flores for responding. As you suggested, `http://[ip-address-of-vm]:4000` is `http://[192.168.99.100]:4000`.  yet is doesn't work. I replaced the `0.0.0.0` with `127.0.0.2` , and tried with different ports still , no success.

Comment: You need to try it without the square brackets

Comment: Sure, I did without the square brackets. It doesn't work.